# Intel C++ compiler bug? (pointers aliasing)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, intel

I am using Intel C++ compiler 12.0, and working on a program similar to the following, which is very simple and straightforward. The while loop should stop in the first run. However, when I build the code using /O2 flag with the Intel compiler, the while loop never stops. If I disable the optimization, or use visual C++, the loop exits normally. If I change pt->flag to p.flag, which I suppose is the same thing, the loop exits normally too. I think it has something to do with Intel's optimization. Is this a bug in the Intel compiler? or I missed something here?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct para {
    int i;  
    int flag;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    para p;
    p.i = 0;
    p.flag = 1;

    para * pt = &p;
    cout << "loop started" << endl;

    int i;
    while (p.flag) {
        if (p.i == 0) {
            for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
                if (p.flag != 1)
                    break;
            }
            if (i==1) {
                pt->flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "loop stopped" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Updates:
Thanks for everybody's answer. I am confused by the explanation of "pointer aliasing". If p is in the registers and pt can't access it, why the following code will break the while loop with the intel compiler? Firstly "pt->flag = 0;" should never take effect because i=0. Secondly even if it's in effect, shouldn't "pointer aliasing" prevent p being modified?

BTW: Can anybody let me know how to turn on/off the pointer aliasing in Visual Studio with intel compiler? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct para {
    int i;  
    int flag;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    para p;
    p.i = 0;
    p.flag = 1;

    para * pt = &p;
    cout << "loop started" << endl;

    int i=0;
    while (p.flag) {
        if (p.i == 0) {
            //for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
            //  if (p.flag != 1)
            //      break;
            //}
            if (i==1) {
                pt->flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "loop stopped" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Compiles fine on GCC 4.7.1 under MinGW. Loop also ends.

Answer (score 6):

This is a situation known as [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing). You have a variable `p` and a pointer `pt` that points to the same thing as `p`. Many optimisations can be used if the compiler can assume that there is only one "name" for a given variable, and `/O2` for your compiler may enable this assumption. For example, the compiler could keep all the member variables for `p` in registers during the loop, which obviously can't be accessed through a memory pointer.

Check your compiler documentation to find out how to tell it to not assume there are no pointer aliases. This could be a compiler switch or a `#pragma`.

Comment: +1 Exactly the thought that came to my mind as well. While the code doesn't violate strict-aliasing, it seems that ICC is expecting something even more strict.

Comment: I think the situation here is a compiler bug in pointer aliasing handling

Comment: I would not rate this as a compiler bug. This is more "don't write like this". You make the code more complex by passing pointers around and compiler will not be able to guess anything. Exact position of the edge can never be known for sure. App code should not be a compiler test.

Comment: I am confused. If p is in registers and pt can't access it, why the following code breaks the while loop with intel compiler? (which shouldn't by all means)
Sorry can't input code here. Please see updates of my question.

Comment: @KirillKobelev: "compiler bug" is not a matter of opinion. The code has well-defined semantics, and the created executable doesn't match them. It may look like weird code, but such things happen in real life. E.g. when instantiating a template from a library, where the resulting code comes from two different authors working independently.

Comment: @DanXu: compiler optimizations can be finicky. In your first case, `p.flag` is used often and may **therefore** be put in a register. In the second example, it's used less, so the optimizer may decide against using a register.

Comment: @MSalters, "matter of opinion" - you are not right here. Whole programming is a matter of decisions that are based on opinions. In this case compiler was not deep enough to understand the code. I am  sure you can not define a clear rule when it starts to be ok for compiler not to detect the aliasing. Once again. App code should not exploit the edges of compiler capabilities.

Comment: @KirillKobelev: I can very much define that rule; you're looking at it from the wrong side. It is NEVER ok for a compiler to overlook aliasing. Either it proves there is no aliasing, or it assumes there is. It may never assume the absence of aliasing.

Comment: @MSalters, "Either it proves there is no aliasing, or it assumes" - this is statement about the perfect world that I would love to live in, but, well, unfortunately... In fact, aliasing itself is not important. It can be any other complex matter. At this site we should promote writing our own code as good as possible, using best technologies, etc. At the same time we should not stretch other code (including compilers) to the limit. This is my point.